# Routing Error after scaffolding and migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, scaffolding

I created a scaffold without problems

> $ rails generate scaffold New name:string title:string content:text

Rake command to run the migration (no problems as before, table correctly created)

> $ rake db:migrate

Edit app/views/home/index.html.erb

> <%= link_to 'My News', :controller => 'news' %>

I see the home and the link correctly in "http://localhost:3000"; clicking the link "My news" page "http://localhost:3000/news" is loaded without errors.

Now, clicking in the link "New New" generated by Rails, link's target localhost:3000/news/new (source "<a href ="/news/new">New New</ a>"), i read this error:

> Routing Error
>
> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"news", :format=>nil}
>
> Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.

In "app/views/news/index.html.erb" the link souce is

> <%= link_to 'New New', new_news_path %>

In routes.rb i read

> MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
>
> resources :news
>
> get "home/index"

- Rails 3.2.3
- Ruby 1.9.3p125
- MySQL 5.5
- Windows 7 64 bit

Rakes routes:

> news_index GET    /news(.:format)          news#index
>
> POST   /news(.:format)          news#create
>
> new_news GET    /news/new(.:format)      news#new
>
> edit_news GET    /news/:id/edit(.:format) news#edit
>
> news GET    /news/:id(.:format)      news#show
>
> PUT    /news/:id(.:format)      news#update
>
> DELETE /news/:id(.:format)      news#destroy
>
> home_index GET    /home/index(.:format)    home#index
>
> root        /                        home#index

Thanks in advance and sorry for my English

Comment: What is the generated link's target? Could you copy that row from the generated source?

Comment: Yes, the link's target is http://localhost:3000/news/new

Answer (score 1):

you have to use `news_index_path` because news is not singular if rails can't make singular - prular distinguish they will add `_index` at the end :)

You have one `news` and many `news` and this is confusing.

Always try to use `<name_of_resource>_path` to generate urls :)

```
news_index GET /news(.:format) news#index
```

This says it implicit, you use 1 part `news_index` and add `_path` to get path for it.

You should have

```
<%= link_to 'My News', news_index_path %>
```

Hope that helps, cheers!

Comment: Thanks,  but i changed ":controller => 'news'" with "news_index_path" in "app/views/home/index.html.erb" and i have the same error clicking on "New New". In "app/views/news/index.html.erb" the link is "<%= link_to 'New New', new_news_path %>"